# How many Homomorphisms are there from one bounded lattice to another?

Tags: combinatorics, lattice-orders

for a project that I work on, I need to know how many homomorphisms there are from one finite lattice with 0 and 1 to another. I remember that I already worked it out if one of them is the trivial lattice {0,1}.

Any ideas?

In detail:

Take two bounded lattices

$L_1,0_1,1_1,\vee_1,\wedge_1$ and
$L_2,0_2,1_2,\vee_2,\wedge_2$

Let $f\in Hom(L_1,L_2)$, then

1. $f(a\vee_1 b)=f(a)\vee_2 f(b)$
2. $f(a\wedge_1 b) = f(a)\wedge_2 f(b)$

And $f \in Hom_{01}(L_1,L_2)$  if

1. $f \in Hom(L_1,L_2)$ and
2. $f(1_1)=1_2$
3. $f(0_1)=0_2$

My question is:

What is $|Hom(L_1,L_2)|$ and  $|Hom_{0,1}(L_1,L_2)|$  ?

Comment: At first, you should define what is a homomorphism from one lattice from one such lattice into another one. Depending on that definition the answer for the trivial case you mention is something between trivial and simple.

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit lazy...

Take a two bounded lattices

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit lazy...

Take two bounded lattices

$L_1,0_1,1_1,\vee_1,\wedge_1$ and
$L_2,0_2,1_2,\vee_2,\wedge_2$


Let $f\in Hom(L_1,L_2)$, then


1. $f(a\vee_1 b)=f(a)\vee_2 f(b)$
2. $f(a\wedge_1 b) = f(a)\wedge_2 f(b)$


And $f \in Hom_{01}(L_1,L_2)$  if


1. $f \in Hom(L_1,L_2)$ and
2. $f(1_1)=1_2$
3. $f(0_1)=0_2$

My question is:

What is |Hom(L_1,L_2)| and  |Hom_{0,1}(L_1,L_2)|  ?

Comment: If $L_1=(\{0,1\},≤)$ then $|Hom(L_1,L_2)| = |{≤}_2|$ where $≤_2$ is the order relation of $L_2$, $|Hom_{0,1}(L_1,L_2)|=1$. $Hom(L_2,L_1)$ provides the order ideals (downsets) or order filters (upsets) of all intervals of $L_2$, while $Hom_{0,1}(L_2,L_1)$ provides the nontrival order ideals and order filters of $L_2$ the missing trivial order filters are: $\emptyset, L_2$. It should be easy to proove this as the complement of an order ideal is an order filter and vice versa.

Comment: The general solution should be sufficiently complicated as the result does not depend only on the size of the lattice, but also on its internal structure. As finite lattices are always complete lattices, the question is: where can I embed the irreducibles. You may ask the question in the setting of Formal Concept analysis asking the question how many different ways are there to embed a reduced context of $L_1$ into a non-reduced context of $L_2$ that hits all non-reducible objects and attributes. Though such questions are discussed there, this one look very special.

Comment: Thanks! 
So it seams that the question is actually a question about embedding. Thanks a lot!